# Both are not the same / Both are not same

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

When saying two things look similar but have some minor differences, which one is correct to say?

> 1. "they both are not the same"
> 2. "they both are not same"

Comment: "The two things are not the same" or "not identical". We would only use 'both' when referring to something that two people or things _do_ have in common, as in "They are both red".

Comment: The nearest you would get to using _both_ in a comparison is when two things are being compared to a third and saying that they are different. In other words 'Both A and B are different from C'. Even when comparing two things with a third we would not use 'both are not the same' if they both differed from the third. We would say 'Neither A nor B is the same as C'